# Get different status description when accessing the same site using HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, azure, http, iis

I experienced a weird thing when deploying my ASP.NET website to Azure WebApp.

In the controller, I returned 401 with error text "Please sign in".

But when I access that controller from client side using HTTP and HTTPS, in both cases I can get the 401 response, but in the HTTP case, the status text is "Please sign in", but in the HTTPS case, the status text is "error".

For example,

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/someUrl",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            success: doSomething,
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // The following line outputs different text when using HTTP vs HTTPS
                // HTTP: Please sign in
                // HTTPS: error
                console.log(jqXHR.statusText); 
            },

            timeout: 180000,
        });
```

May I know what might cause this problem?

Comment: On Azure all sites are behind ARR (reverse proxy), so the error messages might be affected. But your question shows no useful information for others to know your ASP.NET site, nor to see the exact error pages, so you should expect no answer at all.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, thank you for you suggestion, I have made edit to my post. The problem is I got the error message from the status text when making requests using AJAX, there is no error page being shown. Please feel free to let me know what other information I can provide.

Comment: Use the developer tool of your web browser, or a tool like Fiddler from Telerik, and then the whole error page won't escape from you.